# Contract deployment works but method calls fail

Tags: contract-development, private-blockchain

I think it has something to do with my start line

```
geth --datadir ~/final --networkid 98763476 --rpcapi "web3,eth,personal,db,net" --rpcport 888
8 --rpcaddr "ip" --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpc --allow-insecure-unlock
```

I've checked the gas required so that's not the problem
I can deploy contracts, but can't call any methods I either get gas required or always failing transaction or returned values aren't valid did it run out of gas

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;
contract Language {
    function addNumberLanguage(string memory _language) public;
}
contract Text {
    address owner;
    Language language;
    mapping(string => mapping(string => string)) public texts;
    constructor(address _language) public {
        owner = msg.sender;
        language = Language(_language);
    }
    function addText(string memory _language, string memory code, string memory txt) public {
        require(owner == msg.sender, "Unauthorized");
        texts[_language][code] = txt;
    }
    function addLanguage(string memory _language) public {
        require(owner == msg.sender, "Unauthorized");
        language.addNumberLanguage(_language);
    }
}
```

```
const addText = (language, code, txt, cb) => {
    contract.methods.addText(language, code, txt).estimateGas({
        from: account
    }).then(gas => { 
        console.log(gas);
        contract.methods.addText(language, code, txt).send({
            from: account,
            gas: gas
        }).then(res => cb(true, null)).catch(err => cb(false, err));}).catch(err => cb(false, err))
}
```

genesis.json

```
{
    "config": {  
        "chainId": 987, 
        "homesteadBlock": 0,
        "eip150Block": 0,
        "eip155Block": 0,
        "eip158Block": 0
    },
    "difficulty": "0x400",
    "gasLimit": "0x8000000", 
    "alloc": {
        "0x41A3BEBcA1475926A7248aeb6b5CA7C43241d473": {
                "balance": "111111111111111111111111111111"
                }
        }
}}
```

Comment: Probably because `require(owner == msg.sender)` is not satisfied.

Comment: It's the same msg.sender

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changed the genesis.json to

```
{
"config": {
"chainId": 9731,
"homesteadBlock": 0,
"eip150Block": 0,
"eip150Hash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"eip155Block": 0,
"eip158Block": 0,
"byzantiumBlock": 0,
"constantinopleBlock": 0,
"petersburgBlock": 0,
"ethash": {}
},
"nonce": "0x0",
"timestamp": "0x5d5cdc87",
"extraData": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"gasLimit": "0x47b760",
"difficulty": "0x80000",
"mixHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"coinbase": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"alloc": {
"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000": {
  "balance": "0x1"
}
},
"number": "0x0",
"gasUsed": "0x0",
"parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
}
```

and everything works fine!